Moonwalk in the console
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> // Required for usleep() function

int main() {
    // Define ASCII art frames for dancing stick figure with wiggling arms and facial expressions
    char frames[11][11][1000] = {
        {
        "\033[1;33m      o     \033[0m",     // Head
        "\033[1;33m    /¯|¯¯\\   \033[0m",   // Left arm
        "\033[1;32m   /  |  | \033[0m",      // Torso
        "\033[1;32m      /     \033[0m",   // Hips
        "\033[1;33m     /\\    \033[0m",   // Left leg
        "\033[1;32m    /  \\   \033[0m",   // Right leg
        "\033[1;33m  _|   _\\ \033[0m",    // Feet
        "\033[1;32m¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯\033[0m" // Ground
        },
        {
        "\033[1;33m     o     \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m    /¯|¯\\   \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m   |  |  \\  \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m      /     \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m     / \\    \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m    |   \\   \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m   _|   _|  \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯ ¯\033[0m"
        },
{
        "\033[1;33m       o       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m      /¯|\\      \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m     |  | \\     \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m        /        \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m       / \\       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m       |  \\    \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m      _|   /   \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m          \033[0m"
        },
        {
        "\033[1;33m         o       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m        /¯|¯\\      \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m       |  |  \\     \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m          /       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m         \\       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m         |\\    \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m        _| .|   \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m          \033[0m"
        },
        {
        "\033[1;33m          o       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m         /¯|¯\\      \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m        /  |  \\    \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m           /      \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m          \\       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m          |\\    \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m         _| /      \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m          \033[0m"
        },
        {
        "\033[1;33m         o         \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m        /¯|¯\\        \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m       /  |  \\       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m          /            \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m         /\\       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m        \\  \\       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m        _\\  \\     \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m          \033[0m"
        },
        {
        "\033[1;33m         o       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m        /¯|\\      \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m       /  | \\    \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m          |       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m         /\\    \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m        /  \\ \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m       _\\  _| \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m          \033[0m"
        },
        {
        "\033[1;33m         o       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m        /¯|\\      \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m       /  | \\    \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m          |       \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m         /\\    \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m        /  \\ \033[0m",
        "\033[1;33m      _/    _| \033[0m",
        "\033[1;32m          \033[0m"
        },
        {
            "  \\O/   ",
            "   |   ",
            "  / \\  ",
            "        ",
            "   O   ",
            "  /|\\  ",
            "  / \\  "
        },
        {
            "   O   ",
            "  /|\\  ",
            "  / \\  ",
            "       ",
            "  \\O/   ",
            "   |   ",
            "  / \\  "
        },    };

    // Infinite loop to repeat the animation
    while (1) {
        // Loop to display each frame
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // Clear the screen
            printf("\033[2J\033[H");

            // Display the current frame
            printf("Frame %d:\n", i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                printf("%s\n", frames[i][j]);
            }

            // Sleep for a short duration to control the animation speed
            usleep(500000); // Sleep for 500 milliseconds (0.5 seconds)
        }
    }

    return 0;
}



Of course! Here's a refined version of your request:

Hello World!
I'm currently learning C Programming and experimenting with ASCII character animation in the console. Specifically, I'm trying to simulate the moonwalk but facing some challenges in smoothly transitioning between the steps.
My aim is to achieve a seamless transition between the movements of each leg. However, despite my efforts, I'm struggling to make the switch between legs appear fluid.
Could someone experienced in C Programming or ASCII animation lend me a hand? I'd greatly appreciate any tips, tricks, or insights you can offer to help me improve the smoothness of my moonwalk animation.
Thanks in advance for your assistance!
Best regards,
Kyle.
